# QGIS Expression - Show multiple records of other map layers

Tags: qgis

I am working of a map layout in QGIS 3.10. In my layout i am inserting a HTML block. In that HTML block i want to show content by building an expression. This expression will show information from 3 different layers present in map. In below image as show **Fields and Values** is showing attributes of one layer which is being used in map layout Atlas. I want to utilize other layer attributes as well. THere is an option to to do that so i used following

```
 get_feature( 'division1_8cc9f2a7_078a_4d49_8e5a_826e54bc33f1', 'memberOr_5',   "STATE_ABBR"  )
```

But this is returning me first feature of layer which satisfies the queries but there are more then one feature how can i get others ?

[image: ion]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get not only one value, you should use the aggregate function in the expression builder. Your expression should be something like this one:

```
 /*
  collects a comma separated list of the field STATE_ABBR in layer
  division1 with the filter "STATE_ABBR" ='memberOr_5'
 */
 aggregate( 
 layer:='division1',
 aggregate:='concatenate',
 expression:="STATE_ABBR" 
 filter:= "STATE_ABBR" ='memberOr_5', 
 concatenator:=',')
```